# Arrays and pointers arithmetic confusion

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int numbers[5];
  int * p;
  p = numbers;  *p = 10;
  p++;  *p = 20;
  p = &numbers[2];  *p = 30;
  p = numbers + 3;  *p = 40;
  p = numbers;  *(p+4) = 50;
  for (int n=0; n<5; n++)
    cout << numbers[n] << ", ";
  return 0;
}
```

Fairly new coder here. This is an example taken from the pointers page on `cplusplus.com`. They talk about dereferencing, the address of operator, and then they talk about the relationship between arrays and pointers. I noticed if I simply printed out a declared array it spits out the address of the array. I'm really trying to understand exactly what some of these lines of code are doing and am having a hard time.

Everything makes sense up until `*p=10`. I read this as, "the value being pointed to by pointer p is equal to 10" but an `array` isn't just one value. In this case it's 5... So, whats the deal? Will the compiler just assume we are talking about the first element of the array?

Even more confusing for me is `p++;`. `p` right now is the address of the array. How do you do `p=p+1` when p is an address?

I understand `p= &numbers[2];`. As well as the following `*p = 30;`.

`p = numbers + 3;` confuses me. Why are we able to take an address and just add `3` to it? And, what does that even mean?

Everything within the for loop makes sense. It's just printing out the array correct?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: pointer arithmetic. adding to a pointer moves it by the size of the element it points to.

Comment: Now that you have learned about pointer arithmetics, another more important lecture: Don't use it. You have std::vector, std::array and std::list. Those are far more safe than raw arrays. Only place I can think about where you should is deep deep within a class that wraps it. Like you creating a class that stores a 2D-image in a 1D-array, but even then, std classes are probably be better to use. Raw pointers should also be used with caution (if you have the newest C++, you should prefer shared_ptr and unique_ptr, outside of wrapping classes, only use raw pointers when you point to the stack)

Comment: (And go with `using namespace std;` only when in a CPP, preferably not at all. std is big and can easily cause clashes. Get single functions and classes out of the namespace instead: `using std::cout; using std::endl;`)

Answer (score 2):

As Pointed out this due to pointer arithmetic.
So both array `numbers` and pointer `p` are int, so after assigning `numbers`'s base address to pointer `p` and the `*p=10` does `numbers[0]=10`

**Now when you do p++ the address of p is incremented but not to the next numeric value as in normal arithmetic operation of `++` but to the address of the next index of `numbers`.**

Let's assume a int is 4byte of memory and `numbers`'s initial address is 1000.
So `p++` makes address it to be incremented to 1004 which is `numbers[1]` 
Basically it points to the next int variable position in memory. 
So when `*p = 20` is encountered the value 20 will be assigned to the next adjacent memory i.e. 1004 or `numbers[1]=20`.

After that the `p` directly assigned address of 3rd index `numbers[2]` i.e 1008 (next int var in memory). Now `p` is pointing to the 3rd index of `numbers` so `*p=30` is again `numbers[2]=30`

`p = numbers + 3;  *p = 40;` does similar thing that is assigns base address of numbers incremented by 3 indexes (1000 + 3*sizeof(int) =1012 ==>  1000 + 3*4 =1012)  to `p` and assigns 40 to that. so it becomes equivalent to `numbers[3]=40`.

Then `p = numbers;  *(p+4) = 50;` is assigning 1000 to `p` and the adding `4` to the address of `p` by using the `()` and assigns 50 to the value by using `*()` which is value of the address(1000+ 4*4 = 1016) inside the braces.

Answer (score 1):

Using a pointer like this in C++: `p = numbers` makes p point to the **first** element of the array. So when you do `p++` you are making `p` point to the second element.

Now, doing `*p = 10` assigns `10` to whatever `p` is pointing to, as in your case `p` is pointing to the first element of the array, then `*p = 10` is the same as `numbers[0] = 10`.

In case you see this later: `*(p + i) = 20`, this is pointer arithmetic and is the same as `p[i] = 20`. That's why `p[0] = 10` is equivalent to `*(p + 0) = 10` and equivalent to `*p = 10`.

And about your question: `How do you do p=p+1 when p is an address?`: as arrays in C++ are stored sequentially in memory, if the element `p` is pointing at memory address `6400010` then `p++` points at `6400014` assuming each element pointed by `p` occupies 4 bytes. If you wonder why `p++` is `6400014` instead of `6400011`, the reason is a little magic C++ does: when increasing a pointer, it doesn't increase by `1 byte` but by `1 element` so if you are pointing to integers, each one occupying `4 bytes`, then `p` will be increased by `4` instead of `1`.

Comment: thank you for the detailed response! I still am scratching the surface (as in I know nothing) on memory and understanding WHY knowing how many bytes something takes up is important. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down:

```
int numbers[5];
int * p;
```

Assigning the array variable to a pointer means that the pointer will be pointing to the first element:

```
p = numbers;      // p points to the 1st element
*p = 10;          // 1st element will be 10

p++;              // go to next location i.e. 2nd element
*p = 20;          // 2nd element will be 20
```

You can do pointer arithmetic and it works according to the type. Incrementing an `int` pointer on a `32-bit` machine will do a jump of `4` bytes in memory. On a `64-bit` machine, that will be `8` bytes. Keep in mind that you cannot do this with a `void` pointer.

```
p = &numbers[2];   // assign the address of 3rd element
*p = 30;           // 3rd element will be 30

p = numbers + 3;   // numbers + 3 means the address of 4th element
*p = 40;           // 4th element will be 40

p = numbers;       // p points to the 1st element
*(p + 4) = 50;     // p + 4 means the address of 5th element
                   // dereference 5th location and assign 50
                   // 5th element will be 50
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of pages on the web on how pointers work. But there are a couple things to quickly point out.

```
int* p;
```

The above line mean p is a pointer to an int. Assigning something to it doesn't change what it is. It is a pointer to an int, not an array of int.

```
int number[5];
p = number;
```

This assignment takes the address where the array is stored, and assigns it to p. p now points to the beginning of that array.

```
p++;
```

p now points to the 2nd int in the array. Pointers are incremented by the size of the object they point to. So the actual address may increase by 4 or 8, but it goes to the next address of an int.

```
*p = 30;
```

This is an assignment, not a comparison. It doesn't say that what p points to is 30, it copies 30 into the address pointed to by p. Saying "equals" is generally confusing in programming terms, so use either "assign" or "compare" to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

**1>** `p=numbers;`
 
 pointer `p` now points to the start of the array, i.e first element.
**2>** `*p=10;`
   first element now becomes 10, as `p` is pointing to the first element.


**3>** `p++;`
   this moves the pointer to the next element of the array, i.e second element
 
   So, again `*p=20;` will make `second element=20`
**4>** `p = &numbers[2];`
   this statement means that `p` now points to 3rd element of the array.
   So, `*p = 30;` will make `3rd element=30`
**5>** `p = numbers + 3;` 
   Wen we do `p=numbers+1;` it points to second element, so `p=numbers+3;` will now point to 4th element of array.  `*p = 40;` make the `fourth element=40`
**6>** `p = numbers;`
   Again `p` points to first element of array
   `*(p+4) = 50;` will now make `5th element=50`